# Javascript logic - How does the FOR loop know which array to access automatically

Tags: javascript

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];


for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++){
if (i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0){
    console.log("FizzBuzz")
}
else if (i%3 === 0){
    console.log("Fizz")
}
else if (i%5 === 0){
    console.log("Buzz")
}
else {
    console.log(i)
}}
```

Hello!

This code is one of the solutions on codecademy.  I was wondering how the FOR loop knows to access the 'myArray' array to find the value of 'i'.  I never mention 'myArray' in the FOR loop, yet it knows.  I'm confused because what if I had wanted the FOR loop to access another array?  What is the logic of the FOR loops?

Thanks so much everyone.

Comment: I couldn't see the array myArray using inside your for loop...

Comment: If that *is* a [verbatim] solution from "Code Academy", time to find a different site ..

Comment: @user2864740, All code has bugs. File a bug report.

Comment: @zzzzBov That is rubbish. A site *teaching* people (and especially with such trivial code) should be bug free and teach good practices - the *authors* should be extra diligent in this case, just as if they were publishing a real book. I stand by my comment. I am not the internet police (although maybe I do try and police SO too much) and can't fix all the broken crap out there. I can, however, warn the OP that they may want to select a different resource ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't access the array, it simply simulates the array by incrementing i.

if you were to change myArray to say `[2,3,5,6,7,24,50]` (or something that isn't an easily calculated sequence), then the code will fail.

a more correct solution would be:

```
var myArray = [/* numbers go here */];

myArray.forEach(function(i) {
    if (i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (i%3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if (i%5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't. `myArray` is never used.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `myArray` and you'll see that it still works the same. What you're doing is setting `i` to `1` and then counting up until 21. This would give the same results as iterating through an array of ordered numbers.

Comment: the loop goes from 1 to 20

Comment: Right, it loops until it hits 21.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're here after:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];


for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++){
if (i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0){
    console.log(myArray[i]+"is FizzBuzz")
}
else if (i%3 === 0){
    console.log(myArray[i]+"is Fizz")
}
else if (i%5 === 0){
    console.log(myArray[i]+"is Buzz")
}
else {
    console.log(i)
}}
```

Comment: wrong ::  myArray[i]===i+1  if divided by 3  is buzz and u write  4 is buzz http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz

Answer (score 0):

It does not access myArray

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++){
if (i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0){
    document.write("FizzBuzz, ");
}
else if (i%3 === 0){
     document.write("Fizz, ");
}
else if (i%5 === 0){
     document.write("Buzz, ");
}
else {
     document.write(i+", ");
}}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz